# CS0460 Constraints error on decompiled DLL project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am getting this error

> CS0460    Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation
> methods are inherited from the base method, so they cannot be
> specified directly, except for either a 'class', or a 'struct'
> constraint.   QuestradeAPI.Net

And these are the classes.
IVisitor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace QuestradeAPI.Net.Internals
{
internal abstract class IVisitor
{
    protected IVisitor()
    {
    }

    internal abstract void EndObject<T>(T t)
    where T : class;

    internal abstract void StartObject<T>(T t)
    where T : class;

    internal abstract void VisitBasicArrayField<T>(List<T> v, string name);

    internal abstract void VisitBasicArrayField<T>(List<T> v, string name, bool implDepVar);

    internal abstract void VisitBasicField<T>(ref T v, string name);

    internal abstract void VisitBasicField<T>(ref T v, string name, bool implDepVar);

    internal abstract void VisitEnumArrayField<E>(List<E> v, string name)
    where E : struct, IConvertible;

    internal abstract void VisitEnumArrayField<E>(List<E> v, string name, bool implDepVar)
    where E : struct, IConvertible;

    internal abstract void VisitEnumField<E>(ref E v, string name)
    where E : struct, IConvertible;

    internal abstract void VisitEnumField<E>(ref E v, string name, bool implDepVar)
    where E : struct, IConvertible;

    internal abstract void VisitObjectArrayField<T>(List<T> v, string name)
    where T : IVisitable, new();

    internal abstract void VisitObjectArrayField<T>(List<T> v, string name, bool implDepVar)
    where T : IVisitable, new();

    internal abstract void VisitObjectField<T>(T v, string name)
    where T : IVisitable;

    internal abstract void VisitObjectField<T>(T v, string name, bool implDepVar)
    where T : IVisitable;
}
}
```

IVisitable

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace QuestradeAPI.Net.Internals
{
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("785CD17F-305C-41EF-9025-9127FC365262")]
public abstract class IVisitable
{
    protected IVisitable()
    {
    }

    internal abstract void AcceptVisitor<Visitor>(Visitor v)
    where Visitor : IVisitor;

    internal virtual void SetRateLimitRemainingRequestsCount(ulong remainingRequestsCount)
    {
    }

    internal virtual void SetRateLimitRequestsResetTime(DateTime requestsResetTime)
    {
    }
}
}
```

MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest

```
using Questrade.BusinessObjects.Entities;
using QuestradeAPI;
using QuestradeAPI.Net.Internals;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Questrade.Protocol
{
internal class MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest : IVisitable
{
    public string m_accountNumber = "";

    public ulong m_symbolId;

    public string m_primaryRoute = "";

    public string m_secondaryRoute = "AUTO";

    public List<MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest.BracketOrderComponent> m_components = new List<MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest.BracketOrderComponent>();

    public MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest()
    {
    }

    internal override void AcceptVisitor<Visitor>(Visitor v)
    where Visitor : IVisitor
    {
        v.StartObject<MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest>(this);
        v.VisitBasicField<string>(ref this.m_accountNumber, "accountNumber", false);
        v.VisitBasicField<ulong>(ref this.m_symbolId, "symbolId", false);
        v.VisitBasicField<string>(ref this.m_primaryRoute, "primaryRoute", false);
        v.VisitBasicField<string>(ref this.m_secondaryRoute, "secondaryRoute", false);
        v.VisitObjectArrayField<MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest.BracketOrderComponent>(this.m_components, "components", false);
        v.EndObject<MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest>(this);
    }

    public class BracketOrderComponent : IVisitable
    {
        public double m_limitPrice;

        public double m_stopPrice;

        public OrderType m_orderType;

        public OrderTimeInForce m_timeInForce;

        public OrderClass m_orderClass;

        public ulong m_orderId;

        public double m_quantity;

        public OrderAction m_action;

        public BracketOrderComponent()
        {
        }

        internal override void AcceptVisitor<Visitor>(Visitor v)
        where Visitor : IVisitor
        {
            v.StartObject<MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest.BracketOrderComponent>(this);
            v.VisitBasicField<double>(ref this.m_limitPrice, "limitPrice", false);
            v.VisitBasicField<double>(ref this.m_stopPrice, "stopPrice", false);
            v.VisitEnumField<OrderType>(ref this.m_orderType, "orderType", false);
            v.VisitEnumField<OrderTimeInForce>(ref this.m_timeInForce, "timeInForce", false);
            v.VisitEnumField<OrderClass>(ref this.m_orderClass, "orderClass", false);
            v.VisitBasicField<ulong>(ref this.m_orderId, "orderId", false);
            v.VisitBasicField<double>(ref this.m_quantity, "quantity", false);
            v.VisitEnumField<OrderAction>(ref this.m_action, "action", false);
            v.EndObject<MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest.BracketOrderComponent>(this);
        }

        public static implicit operator BracketOrderComponent(Questrade.BusinessObjects.Entities.BracketOrderComponent srcItem)
        {
            MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest.BracketOrderComponent bracketOrderComponent = new MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest.BracketOrderComponent()
            {
                m_limitPrice = srcItem.m_limitPrice,
                m_stopPrice = srcItem.m_stopPrice,
                m_orderType = srcItem.m_orderType,
                m_timeInForce = srcItem.m_timeInForce,
                m_orderClass = srcItem.m_orderClass,
                m_orderId = srcItem.m_orderId,
                m_quantity = srcItem.m_quantity,
                m_action = srcItem.m_action
            };
            return bracketOrderComponent;
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image: Error message]

I have decompiled a DLL file and made a project using that. I am getting a build error like mentioned above. Thanks in advance to anyone who can identify the issue.

Comment: try to change `internal abstract void AcceptVisitor<Visitor>(Visitor v)
    where Visitor : IVisitor;` to `internal virtual void AcceptVisitor<Visitor>(Visitor v)
    where Visitor : IVisitor;`

Comment: I mean you need to provide an empty body as `{`  `}`

Comment: that didn't work, getting the same constraint error "CS0460 Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation.."

Answer (score 0):

Restricting the Visitor in the method must inherit the IVisitor interface, but this cannot be written in the method.  See [Compiler Error CS0460](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0460)

You can inherit an interface on a class like the code below.It is recommended to start by designing a good type.

```
public abstract class IVisitor{}
internal class MsgBracketOrderImpactRequest : IVisitable
{
   internal override void AcceptVisitor<Visitor>(Visitor v) 
   {
              ...
   }

   internal override void AcceptVisitor<Visitor>(Visitor v)  
   {
            ...
    }
}
public class Visitor : IVisitor {}
```